# AWS DynamoDB Conditional Item Deletion

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have a DynamoDB table with one attribute as a primary key `ItemName`.

Every attribute that is added to the table is named using the current UTC timestamp.

I want to do a conditional deletion of the item when I delete the last attribute which will check if there's another attribute other than `ItemName` and if there isn't I want to delete the item.

Is there anyway to do so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there isn't a way to tell DynamoDB to automatically do this for you. They will create a new item for you if you use the [UpdateItem](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html) method to to add an attribute to an item that doesn't already exist, but they won't automatically delete the item when all attributes (except for the key) have been deleted.

The best way to do this is by using the [ReturnValues](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html#DDB-UpdateItem-request-ReturnValues) attribute of the UpdateItem method. Set it to `ALL_NEW` to get the current state of the row returned back to you. Your code can then check if there are any additional attributes on the item and call the [DeleteItem](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteItem.html) method, as appropriate.

EDIT:
Further, you can add a [ConditionExpression](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteItem.html#DDB-DeleteItem-request-ConditionExpression) to the `DeleteItem` method call to check for the existence of an attribute before you delete it.

Comment: Thank you @coffeeplease, what I did was getting the item after deleting the attribute which is obviously not as good. the thing is that it still doesn't solve my problem because after I finish checking for new attributes and until I delete the Item, another attribute can be created somewhere else and I'll simply delete it. Sorry for not being clear about the way I create items/delete attributes. Thanks anyway

Comment: Even if you were able to delete the item, if another attribute came in, would it use UpdateItem to add that attribute? If that's the case, it would end up recreating the item. Is that what you want? I'm curious about your scenario if you are able to share any additional details...

Comment: If I were able to delete the item and only then use UpdateItem to add an attribute then I will have no problem with the item recreation. but I don't want to delete the item if new attributes were created before deleting it. I'm using a table to manage locking mechanism. I can have multiple read locks per account and only one write lock (separately)

Comment: You can also make your DeleteItem call conditional, using the ConditionExpression parameter. I edited my answer to add this information.

Comment: The problem with it is that I use UTC Timestamp as my attributes' names so I can't use the attribute_not_exists/attribute_exist

Comment: And what value do the attributes hold?

Comment: strings (custom type serialized into JSON)

Comment: Yeah, there doesn't seem to be a way to run a function on an attribute without knowing its name. You may want to ask about this in the Amazon DynamoDB forums. They are hit and miss, but sometimes I get a helpful response. Even if they provided the ability to know how many attributes are on an item, that could help with conditional writes/deletes.